# Deleting child model with additional logic

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a parent model and a child model, say Categories and Posts. The `Post` model can have a featured image attached to it which needs to be removed from storage when the post is deleted, so in my `PostController` my `destroy` method looks like this:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

    if ($post->featured_image_path) {
        Storage::delete($post->featured_image_path);
    }

    $post->delete();

    return redirect('/admin/posts');
}
```

My `CategoryController` has a similar `destroy` method, however it also needs to remove each of its `Post`s when it gets destroyed. I know I can use a foreign key and rely on the relationship to delete the posts, but when doing that the featured images aren't removed from storage. I could loop through each `$category->posts()` in my `Category@delete` method and check for featured images, but it doesn't seem right to duplicate this logic in multiple places.

What is the best way to run the logic from the `destroy` method on my `Post` when deleting a `Category` in the `CategoryController`?

Comment: I think its better to collect all `$post->featured_image_path` in an array or something then send it to a cleanup job and proceed with your normal relationship delete.

Comment: @CerlinBoss how would you tie the cleanup job to the relationship delete?

Comment: as i said. First collect the location of the files to be deleted in an array, then dispatch the job for cleaning, the proceed with your normal delete procedure. Or dispatch the cleanup job after successful deletion of `$category` and `$posts`

Comment: Using observers and an `OberverServiceProvider` would be a cleaner solution imo. See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#observers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an approach like this.

Change your `Category` model like this.

```
class Categories extends Model

{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleted(function ($object) {
            // Logic to delete Post goes here...
        });
    }
}
```

`Post` model like this.

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleted(function ($object) {
            // Logic to delete FeatureImage goes here...
        });
    }
}
```

So when ever a `Category` is deleted it's corresponding `Post`, and then the `Image` will be deleted according to your logic.

As an enhancement you can fire `events` inside `deleted()` method

Comment: I like this approach, especially with the possibility of firing an event on delete.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: Yes you can use Laravel Observers to extract above logic and clean your Models. This comes handy when you are listening to many events on a given Model.